# Adding MergedDictionaries to styles via code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this `style` in a Resource-File:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="StandardTextBox"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Color1}"/>
            </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

(Colors.xaml contains my `brushes`)

My Code to use the `style`:

```
ResourceDictionary TetxboxStyles = new ResourceDictionary();
TetxboxStyles.Source = (new Uri("TextboxStyles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(TetxboxStyles);
tb_input.Style = (Style)Find("StandardTextBox");
```

This works without a problem but it doesn't work when I dynamically add the Colors-Resource via code instead of in the TextboxStyles-File:

```
ResourceDictionary TetxboxStyles = new ResourceDictionary();
TetxboxStyles.Source = (new Uri("TextboxStyles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

//Adding the Colors.xaml Resource
ResourceDictionary Colors = new ResourceDictionary();
brushes.Source = (new Uri("Colors.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
TetxboxStyles.MergedDictionaries.Add(Colors);

Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(TetxboxStyles);
tb_input.Style = (Style)Find("StandardTextBox");
```

Output-Error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
```

`"{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}"`

Comment: Do you want to paint your TextBox by ResourceDictionary "Brushes.xaml"?

Comment: File that contains style: TextboxStyles.xaml
, 
File that contains brushes: Colors.xaml

The Textbox has its style from TextboxtStyles.xaml while TextboxSyles.xaml has its colors/brushes from Colors.xaml

Comment: Why do you need to apply multiple ResourceDictionaries to one control(to your TextBox)? Cause you should write your own own template in one ResourceDictionary where you can define colors and brushes of your controls like that https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752068(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It was examplary. I wanted to add a Resource to another Resource.

Comment: In the original code I use
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}">
to make it apply to every textbox

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `StaticResource` with `DynamicResource` and it works